# Wofür soll das Tag "political correctness" stehen?

Tags: discussion

Bei [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/41439/1696) ist das Tag "political correctness" zugewiesen. Meiner Meinung nach hat das Tag mit der korrekten Aussprache fremdländischer Vokabeln aber nicht zu tun. Der Erläuterungstext zum Tag hilft aber auch nicht wirklich weiter...

Comment: Das Tag-Wiki für [tag:political-correctness] ist offensichtlich falsch und muss korrigiert werden. ([Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politische_Korrektheit) abschreiben ist aber auch nicht der richtige weg.)

Comment: Hab eine kl. Änderung vorgenommen. In den 70ern/80ern grenzten sich die politischen Lager voneinander ab, wobei die einen stur AKW sagten, die anderen stur KKW. Der Mehrheit der Bevölkerung dürfte die Bezeichnung wurscht gewesen sein. Weder benutzen nur angebl. Progressive PC, noch sind alle Kritiker an dieser Konservative.